# Google Actions - remove cache before calling the intents

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk, api-ai

I am building an action in which I am using an image card and my image is present in the dropbox location.

It works really fine but my use case is I need to replace the existing image every week. But when I do so, it still picks up the old image probably coz its present in my cache.

Now, I know that I can go to myactivity and remove the cache for google assistant but I cannot ask the users to do the same.

So what I want is, when a user tries to open my google action for the 2nd or 3rd time, it should pick up the new image instead of the existing image which he has already previewed it.

Comment: Is the cache related to Dropbox? If you used a different host, would you see the newer image?

Comment: @NickFelker, Yes.. With new host, I see the newer image(say version 2).. but then If I change to version 3 image, this new host will show the version 2 image as that image is already cached onto that host.  There has to be a way out wherein it should pick up the new image from the Dropbox link.

Comment: Different services have their own caches. You may need to use a host provider like a web host, where you have more control over the cache time.